# How to trigger Navigation when an Reanimated 2 Animation is completed? React Native - Reanimated 2 & React-Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-animations

I'm trying to create a Tinder clone where there is a left and right swiping mechanism for liking and disliking a profile. However, I want the user to swipe the profile downwards to open the profile details screen. I have tried creating the function directly in ".onEnd" but every time I perform the swipe action, it completely crashes the app. Every other swipe direction works perfectly as expected. I have tried resetting the cache, uninstalling the app on the emulator and that hasn't fixed it. I couldn't find a solution on the documentation or anywhere on Google.

Thanks for the help in advance! This is my first programming project! :D

Here's my current code:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";
import ListingDetails from "../ListingDetails";
import { listingsArr } from "../Listings";
import Animated, { useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle, withSpring } from "react-native-reanimated";
import { GestureDetector, Gesture } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import ListingDetailScreen from "../../Screens/ListingDetailScreen";
import {MainStackNavigator } from '../../Navigation/MainStackNavigator';




const SingleCard = (props) => {

  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const navigateToHome = () => {navigation.navigate('Home')}

  console.log(useWindowDimensions().height)
  const windowWidth = useWindowDimensions().width
  const windowHeight = useWindowDimensions().height
  const startPosition = 0;
  const x = useSharedValue(startPosition)
  const y = useSharedValue(startPosition)



  const isPressed = useSharedValue(false);
  const offset = useSharedValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [
        { translateX: withSpring(x.value) },
        { translateY: withSpring(y.value) },
      ],
      backgroundColor: isPressed.value ? 'yellow' : 'blue',
    };
  });

  const start = useSharedValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
    .onBegin(() => {
      isPressed.value = true
    })
    .onUpdate((e) => {

      x.value = startPosition + e.translationX;
      y.value = startPosition + e.translationY;

    })
    .onEnd((e) => {
      const verticalSwipe = Math.abs(y.value) - Math.abs(x.value);
      const horizontalSwipe = Math.abs(x.value) - Math.abs(y.value);
      console.log(verticalSwipe)
      console.log(y.value)

      if (verticalSwipe >= 0) {
        if (y.value > windowHeight / 4) { 
          navigateToHome();
          
          console.log('swiped up')
        } else {
          x.value = withSpring(startPosition);
          y.value = withSpring(startPosition);
        }
      } else {
        if (x.value > windowWidth / 4) {
          x.value = withSpring(windowWidth * 2);
          y.value = withSpring(startPosition)

        } else if (x.value < windowWidth / -4) {
          x.value = withSpring(windowWidth * -2);
          y.value = withSpring(startPosition);
          console.log('swiped left')

        } else {
          x.value = withSpring(startPosition);
          y.value = withSpring(startPosition);
        }
      }

    })
    .onFinalize(() => {
      isPressed.value = false;
    });


  return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.masterContainer, animatedStyles]} >
        <View style={styles.spacerContainer}>
        </View>

        <Text> This is single card component </Text>

        <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={props.cardListing.Photo} />

        <LinearGradient colors={['rgba(255,255,255,0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4 )']} style={styles.backgroundOverlay} />
        <ListingDetails myListing={props.cardListing} />


      </Animated.View>
    </GestureDetector>
  )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  spacerContainer: {
    flex: 2,
  },


  containerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  imageStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    flex: 1,
  },

  imageContainer1: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    zIndex: 0,
    flex: 1
  },

  imageContainer2: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    flex: 1,
    zIndex: 0,
  },

  backgroundOverlay: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 0,

  },

  masterContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',

  }
})

export default SingleCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `RunOnJS` from reanimated lib like example below:
Explaining, animated is running in UI Thread and `navigation.navigate` function run in another thread (JS Thread), then animated can't call navigate function.
More in [reanimated documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/miscellaneous/runOnJS/).

```
import Animated, { runOnJS, useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated';

// ...other codes

  const settingsIconRotation = useSharedValue(0);

  const onPressFn = () => {
    // function from other thread (different of reanimated thread)
    navigation.navigate('Modal');
  };

  const onPressSettings = () => {
    settingsIconRotation.value = withSpring(180, {}, (finished) => {
      if (finished) {
        settingsIconRotation.value = 0;
        runOnJS(onPressFn)(); // execute on JS thread
      } else {
      }
    });
  };
  
// ...other codes
```